# What is a non-bipartite matching problem and what are some of the real life applications of non-bipartite matching?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I know what bipartite matching is. In bipartite matching, we look for a one-to-one match between two disjoint sets of vertices. A classic real-life example of bipartite matching is [matching kidneys](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1010&context=rhumj). I am wondering what non-bipartite matching is really about and where we may want to solve non-bipartite matching problems in real life.

1. Does non-bipartite matching refers to cases where we have more than two disjoint sets of vertices (such as tripartite)?
2. Does non-bipartite matching mean that we have a bipartite network, but we can also have matching *within* a specific set?
3. 1. and 2. both can happen?

Comment: I would think a bipartite matching would be a matching of items of one type with items of a different type, whereas a non-bipartite matching would be a matching of items of one type with other items of the same type (that is, a matching of items in the same set).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I think your comment refers to the second case that I mentioned in my question. Can we have both *within* the same set and *between* two different set matchings at the same time?

Comment: I don't know. It seems to me that either you have a matching between set $A$ and set $B$, or else you have a matching on a set $A$. I suppose you could have a matching where some elements of $A$ are matched with elements of $B$, and some elements of $A$ (respectively, $B$) are matched with elements of $A$ (respectively, $B$). I wouldn't call that bipartite.